# Create meta-task TFS15 RC1

Tags: tfs

When I try to create a meta-task in TFS15 RC1 the following error come on;

Access denied. [username] needs Edit meta-task permissions to perform the action. For more information, contact the Team Foundation Server administrator.

The user in question is a superadmin of TFS15.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lack of the related permission, you can give the permission follow below step:

1. Open **Meta-task** under Release hub in your team project
2. Right click Meta-task select **Security**
3. Either **add your account in one of the groups** or **directly add your
   User ID** (click *Add...-Add Windows identity*)

[image]

*Note:*

- Please make sure the permission for **Edit meta-task** of your
  account or the TFS group  has been set **Allow**.
- When you add the new user ID under the users, you need to change
  permission (such as Not set-Allow) and **save changes**. Otherwise,
  the user will disappear.